# How to compute probability distribution function of $X+Y$ using the distribution functions of $X$ and $Y$?

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables which are continuous but does not necessarily have density. How can I get the distribution function of $X+Y$ in terms of the distributions of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Are $X$ $Y$ independent?